# How to use dependencies from a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I am trying to import a jar file and to use its dependencies into a Maven project.
The jar file I want to import is itself another Maven project and includes all of the dependencies of it.

I managed to import my jar file and to use the java code (from my packages in src/main in the Maven project jar file) but the project where I imported mt jar file still does not recognize the dependencies of the jar.

For example, I am trying to import org.json.JSONObject (whom dependency is defined in the jar file) but there is a compiling error.

Is there any way to do what I want or any other solution ?

Thank you !

(Sorry for the bad level of explanation, I am French and it is quite hard form me to explain in details my problem)

**EDIT**

Here are samples of my pom from my jar file :

```
<!-- One of the dependency I want to use -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- The plugin I used to create my jar file with dependencies -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I then included the jar file using an "in-project" repository as explained here : http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/

The error message is a compiling error message saying that the org.json.JSONObject is not recognized :
`package org.json does not exist`

Comment: Show pom and error message

Comment: Remove `<scope>test</scope>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the json lib only for test scope.

Remove the scope and the error should gone.

```
<!-- One of the dependency I want to use -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```